# Specific User to run only one app, not Windows explorer nor etc

Tags: windows, touch, slideshow

I am looking for a solution for the following problem:
On a **tablet** running **Windows 7,8 or 10** having a **slideshow** app running full-screen such that **automatically** and **by touch** photos are shown. I want to have **no control button or any other controls** at all. Just **simply the photo**. More importantly I want to have **only this app accessible by user**, so that in terms of crash or restart this app will only execute. The user **must not be able to see the desktop nor Windows explorer or any other app**.
I am thinking if possible to create a very limited user account that meets the above limitations strictly.
**Any idea?**

Comment: I know that `XnView` for example can show the slideshow. How to make it the only app that can be run by the specific user? If crashed log off and other details as explained in the question.

Comment: You are looking for [kiosk mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn499738.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I noticed that Kiosk mode (which is BTW exact solution) only works on PRO and UP editions of Windows. Is there any way to enable it on Windows 7, 8 and 10 HOME editions as well? If not, any other alternative?